# Is there any performance impact of having transaction control implemented in ado.net code?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ado.net

I am supposed to tune a .net application, where the developers have implemented transaction control in ado.net even for connections with single sql command.
Personally, I avoid ado.net transaction control in such scenarios and implement it on the db side. I believe there's a call to db for each ado.net transaction control command in addition to the one for sql command, which will cause a performance hit.
I understand on the backend, both are equivalent. I want to know if it's an issue and if it is, then how significant.

Comment: Generally you would call a Stored Proecedure from ADO.NET and implement a BEGIN TRAN, COMMIT TRAN in the Stored Procedure.

Comment: @cvraman "generally" is generally an over-generalisation

Comment: @Marc : True... But since the person who posted this question had a database to connect to and was anxious about performance, I made the comment in that context.

Comment: @cvraman which I disagree with ;p I've seen all sorts of approaches here, enough to say that a sweeping statement like "Generally you would..." is problematic.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I have always implemented it in T-SQL code, so perhaps I am a bit biased there. Would like to know the alternative approach though.

Comment: @cvraman could use connection primitives (as per the OP), could use ambient transaction (LTM, DTC, etc); could use SQL but not involving any stored procedures; could use a data access technology that isn't ADO.NET. Actually, I do a lot of network/IO code, and one thing I'm toying with is writing a raw TDS API - this would allow me to pipeline operations without incurring latency cost (especially for the begin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not it is an issue depends on how fast you need it to be. The time involved here is basically going to be an extra 2 x {latency} (one for "begin", one for "commit" / "rollback"), where {latency} is dependent on your network, but *typically* about 0.25ms; so - call it 0.5ms per operation. In most scenarios, by itself this 0.5ms will be irrelevant, especially compared to the actual "doing" code. If you are making enough trips to the DB that this is an important number, then the first thing I would change would be: make fewer trips to the DB.

In most cases, I wouldn't be overly concerned by whether this is implemented in the TSQL vs on the connection : either will work, and it is much easier to ensure that the connection-based approach is *provably correct*. I've seen lots of mistakes in TSQL rollback code...

To know for sure, you would have to profile, but again: keep in mind that the time will usually be a: isolated (i.e. not 200 of these per page, etc), and/or b: swamped by the actual "doing" code

Comment: I wasn't actually concerned with this when I had just seen the code. From VS Profiler instrumentation report, I can see each of these methods take 40-50 ms, which of course includes the actual command execution on the db server(and I've recorded that too which never crosses single digit). Could be a network issue I guess but haven't got any other server to test right now. Wanted to know if it's a general problem

Comment: @meraj well, profiling is probably your best bet. Something like mini-profiler might help. Note: once you are running in a transaction, the code has to run differently to meet the guarantees - and will almost always be a bit slower. This is not dependent on *how* you create the transaction (except to say as a caveat that different transaction techniques have different default "isolation level"s - which by itself is a good reason to specify the isolation level explicitly rather than using defaults). It could be that any perceived slow-down is due to the isolation level.